# connect to remote Database in IOS

Tags: mysql, ios, objective-c

i'm trying to develop an app that needs access to a remote database stored on my web server, i have looked online and all the tutorials i can find are about sqlite3 and only show using local databases, any answered questions are vague and dont really answer the question.

there was mention of PHP/XML on one answer, nothing more specific than "use PHP or XML" - both of which i have never used

could someone point me to a tutorial, or explain what i will need to do to connect to my database?

Comment: Have you considered using something like https://parse.com/? You sound a little in over your head - you're going to have to learn a server-side programming language like PHP if you do this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Connecting from an iOS device directly to a remote database system is generally not a good idea for several reasons:

- The database has to be open to all of the Internet, which is a bad idea for security reasons. You probably have heard of SQL injection; this is worse. Everyone can connect directly to the database and send any SQL commands they want.
- The database protocol is not designed for high-latency links; it may be ver "chatty" which makes it unusably slow over a WAN.
- (Trying to think of a third...)

That said, technically it can be done. You can probably call the [MySQL C client library](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/) directly from Objective C.

Comment: i'm going to take a look at parse.com (in the comment under my question).   if that doesnt work out, what would you suggest i do to get information from a database onto my app? the app is going to get login details (just that for now)

Comment: parse is a good choice for storage backend, I've used it once though not from Objective C. If it doesn't work out, I believe Amazon and Google have offerings with similar features

Comment: So suppose I have a MySQL database that I'd like to use with an iPhone app. How would I best connect to it, if not directly? What's the best method of interaction?

Comment: @rar most people use a web service of some kind as middleware, so that a server application accepts http requests and transforms them into SQL.

Comment: That's what I figured. So I could effectively write a simple PHP page to process the HTTP requests. I'll probably go for a more advanced web service of some kind, mind you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect your iOS app to a remote database, you need a REST server. There are various ways you can create that including Jackson and [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) frameworks but those take too long and need lot of expertise. There is a new service called [EspressoLogic](http://www.espressologic.com) that claims to provides a fast RESTful service that connects to various remote databases.One of my friends has tried it and liked it.